# Eclipse support for previous APIs

Tags: android

I have formatted my system and have installed "Eclipse - Juno". I have done all the Java path settings and SDK settings as well. But the eclipse shows the minimum target API level is 17 and Android version is 4.2. How do i get it to support API levels from 8 ?

How do i get the previous level SDKs? Can i use the SDK Manager to install them?

Comment: If you have started the Eclipse for the first time, then Go to Windows -> Open Perspective->Other and Select "Java(Default)" and click OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the minumum level api to 8 in your manifest.
Please also remember you have the required sdks installed and eclipse know where you have it.
Also, in your C:\Users{USERNAME}\android-sdks\extras\android\support
Has the v4,v7,13 backward capiabilty support libraries, add it to build path to use previous apis.

Comment: We set it to 8 if you want to support min 8.

Comment: Yeah.. I meant, it was below 17. But if i need to create a new project, it doesn't give me an option to start below 17.

Comment: I think i am missing the previous sdks. Where do i get them?

Comment: Open sdk manager,the icon in green. You will see a list of all sdk avaiable. Also make sure that your adt is up-to-date. Eclipse>Help>updatesoftware.

Comment: he is simply missing the SDKs, that's why Eclipse shows a min SDK of 17

Comment: I am running the eclipse for the first time after the reinstall. I don't find the SDK manager as well as the AVD manager. I heard they will be visible after the first successful run? Is that correct?

Comment: @MarvinLabs or @ Downvoter, Didn't I say in my second sentence about missing sdks?

Answer (score 0):

Have you downloaded the corresponding API level SDKs?

Comment: Do we need to download each API level SDK individually?

Comment: Ok.. will try and get back

Comment: I am running the eclipse for the first time after the reinstall. I don't find the SDK manager as well as the AVD manager. I heard they will be visible after the first successful run? Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

You need to download all your required SDKs. That is, when you install a new instance of the ADT, it only contains the latest API support. To download SDKs follow these steps.

```
Open Eclipse (Juno in your case)

Select Window -> Android SDK Manager
```

Wait for a few seconds till it loads the list of all SDKs (both installed and not installed, see under the status column).

Select the **check boxes** for all the APIs, Tools and Add-ons you want to download and click the **Install nn packages...** button. Select the "**Accept All**" radio button and click **Install** button and wait till it downloads all SDKs.

You may need to provide the correct SDK path if you have altered it during/after your installation.

Hope this helps.